# Figuring out installed packages on Ubuntu from filesystem backup

Tags: debian, ubuntu, package-management, backup

I have a full filesystem backup from my Ubuntu box, and my OS disk crashed.

Is there a way to list all installed packages (like `dpkg -l` does but) from the backup?

The logfiles are not an option as those aren't complete and they list installs, partial installs, and uninstalls etc.

Comment: BTW: If you're trying to recover the machine, and you have a full backup, you should just be able to replace the disk and restore the backup. Maybe change a UUID in /etc/fstab (etc.), re-install grub, and you're done. The machine should boot again, and work just like it did before the failure.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this without `chroot`. This can be useful if you can't run the binaries on the system for any number of reasons (corruption, partial backup, wrong architecture, security compromise...):

1. You can tell `dpkg` to look at an alternate path using the `--admindir` flag. Just point it to `/path-to-restored-files/var/lib/dpkg`. I'd be wary of using this in the case of security compromise, though.
2. You can look at the dpkg status file directly (in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`). It's a plain text file.

Comment: Didn't know 1. was an option. That solves the problem of not wanting to mount rw the backup.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, try the following code if it's not a [dd](/questions/tagged/dd) image :

```
# chroot /path/to/root/backup_filesystem /bin/bash
# dpkg -l
```

even shorter :

```
# chroot /path/to/root/backup_filesystem /usr/bin/dpkg -l
```

Comment: Brilliant! Should have thought of that myself.

Comment: Added a shorter version (one-liner)